# How can I locate an invisible menu item?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, menu

I'm refactoring a body of code, looking through it all, line by line.

I came across an event handler:

```
private void mnuUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

...and, not recognizing which menu item called this (the menu item names do not always match their labels, or even come close), was curious.

The main menu on the form has no such menu item among its children.

I r-clicked the event handler, selected "Find Usages*" and was led here:

```
this.mnuUpdate.Text = "Update";
this.mnuUpdate.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.mnuUpdate_Click);
```

(This is an antedeluvial app that predates .NET's partial class goodness, so this is in the same file)

On the form in the designer, when I select "mnuUpdate" from the properties page combobox, the mainMenu on the form disappears altogether.

How can I track down this fugitive menu item? There is no popupMenu or contextMenu on the form, just the mainMenu control...???

- The only other usage is:

  if (ResetConnectionFetchForm)
      mnuUpdate_Click(sender, e);

Is it possible that this is simply a phantom menu item that should be converted into a "regular old" method?

### UPDATE

As the most intelligent George used to say, "Curiouser and Curiouser." Now I find this:

```
public void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

...and though it is called from seven places in the code, there is no btnCancel on the form...It is a "fake" button click event. Oh my Lanta!!!

So, I replaced it with a parameterless private method with the exact same code (it didn't use either sender or event args).

If the cat who wrote this cockamamie glob of fruitcake-battered spaghetti was deliberately trying to drive the next cat (me) crazy, it's working pretty well, and would make a good Poe-style story or Hitchcock-style flick.

...I see...Dead Code!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, mystery solved. mnuUpdate is dynamically added (conditionally) to mnuSetup (which is a top level menu item with the Text property "Fetch") like so:

```
if (!mnuSetup.MenuItems.Contains(mnuUpdate))
{
    mnuSetup.MenuItems.Add(mnuUpdate);
    UpdateMenuItemSelectable = true;
}
```

I reckon selecting mnuUpdate from the combobox in the form's Properties page is because there is no visual representation to show at that point.

Selecting "mnuSetup" highlights the "Fetch" menu item, but selecting "mnuUpdate" causes it all to scurry away faster than cockroaches from the light.

So the bizarre thing about it now is: why is the menu item not dynamically *created* as necessary, instead of being explicitly created and then dynamically added; seems like a strange way for a cat to skin a cat.

Comment: I was going to suggest finding it with `CTRL+F` and search the entire solution. FWIW: Adding the menu item dynamically is a better idea.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you turn it into "regular old menu" so someone else doesn't waste time figuring it out.

Me - I would have thought it obsolete code because it doesn't have a Handles clause.

You can use .Visible and .Enabled to control what the user sees.